# Using msbuild to publish asp.net web project does not work, but using the one click solution from vs does

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm currently trying to publish my solution using the msbuild commandline function, using a publish profile. But when i publish using this code

```
msbuild D:\path\BWS.IMP.Presentation.Web.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Production
```

I get build succeeded in the command prompt, but on the target site i get

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible.

But if i publish from visual studio using the same profile, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i was using a debug config when i used the msbuild. Adding a configuration parameter fixed my problem.

```
msbuild D:\path\BWS.IMP.Presentation.Web.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;PublishProfile=Production;DeployOnBuild=true
```

Comment: had to wait 24 hours :)